# node Object.assign(obj1,obj2,obj3) returning the json properties of obj3

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some encapsulated mongoose queries to a mongodb.

```
collection1.findOne({ parm: value}, function(err, item){
    var a = item.a;
    var b = item.b;
    collection2.findOne({parm1: a}, function(err, item2){
        collection3.findOne({parm2: b}, function(err, item3){
            var records = Object.assign(item, item2, item3);
        });
    });
});
```

If I print item, item2 and item3 before the assign all objects print different as well as some equal properties. When I print records after the var records line it only shows up item3 json properties.

Per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) it should

> copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Which is not happening. Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior?

I require [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library. Is it possible that imports might be altering the behavior of object.assign?

Comment: Are the keys of the objects equal?

Comment: Some yes and some are not

Comment: It should overlap with the last value, not keep the last json object properties only

Comment: Well those who are equal will be those of the last one assigned, theres no way to have the same key twice in one object.

Comment: Right but all properties should be in the resulting record.

Comment: Could you give some sample `item`s and a sample `records`?

Comment: Can't sorry, but the record json is a copy of obj3. no other property is there

Comment: Then i can't answer.

Comment: @JonasW. I understand but I don't see how the structure and key value pairs of my json object are relevant to the issue I am describing. If any ideas pop up please feel free to reply

Comment: Remember that Object.assign performs a shallow copy, so if the objects are wrapped in a single key. That single key will be overwritten. Ex: in `Object.assign({}, {wrapper: {a:5, b:2}}, {wrapper: {b:3, c:2}})` the expected output is `{wrapper:{b:3, c:2}}` because you are replacing the whole wrapper key with a different object

Comment: @KevinPeña that worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> When I print records after the var records line it only shows up item3
>   json properties.

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.assign)

> iii) if desc is not undefined and desc.[[Enumerable]] is true, then
>
> a) Let propValue be Get(from, nextKey).
>
> b) ReturnIfAbrupt(propValue).
>
> c) Let status be Set(to, nextKey, propValue, true). **//observe this line**
>
> d) ReturnIfAbrupt(status).

So, this is an expected behavior since assign works by

- Assigning values **from left source onwards to right**.
- And **doesn't check if a property has already been set**.

**Demo**

```js
var a = {a:1, b:2};
var b = {b:3, c:4};
var c = Object.assign( {}, a,b );
console.log(c);
```

Observe that the output overrides `b` property

> {   "a": 1,   "b": 3,   "c": 4 }

Comment: When I add {} in Object.assign I get a weird wrapper arount the object. let me update my question with it.

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins The "weird wrapper" is because these are "mongoose documents" and not "plain JavaScript Objects". You need to convert them i.e `Object.assign({},item.toObject(),item2.toObject(),item3.toObject())`. So whilst `console.log()` makes them "appear" as plain objects, they simply are not.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I understand that the properties that will be set for the same keys are the ones in the order of the objects in the assign function. But doesn't make sense to me that it looses some that are not present in subsequent json objects.

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you share the values of `item2` and `item3` in your question?

Comment: @gurvinder372 check my question pls.